# Free travel with S-Bahn with Deutsche Bahn Intercity Ticket

Tags: trains, tickets, deutsche-bahn

I am travelling to Munich from Budapest (Deutsche Bahn). Arriving at Munich Hauptbahnhof. Can I travel for free with S Bahn or U Bahn in the city (given that I have the Budapest ticket)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This depends on the precise destination on the ticket. If it says "+City", then you are allowed to take another train to get to your destination within the city. This option exists for major cities only and the area and conditions vary from city to city. In Munich most of the city is included, shown as "Innenraum" on the local transit maps.

Please see @dunni answer for an additional possibility: If the ticket just mentions Munich and not a specific station (such as Hauptbahnhof / Hbf), you are entitled to continue to any train station (not underground station) in Munich, if the total travel distance is above a certain limit.

If not included, the ticket is valid only to Hauptbahnhof. If necessary, you can book the ticket to any S-Bahn stop as well. U-Bahn, Tram and Buses can not be included on a Deutsche Bahn ticket and require an additional ticket. You can buy this ticket using the Deutsche Bahn mobile app and at ticket machines available throughout the city. Don't forget to stamp the ticket when entering the station (there are no gates that force you to do that).

Comment: You write that 'most of the city is included'. Which exact part of Munich is not covered by the +City ticket option, or perhaps to ask more exact: Which part of Munich is not covered by the 'Innenraum' tariff zone?

Comment: Here is a map of the full Innenraum: http://www.mvv-muenchen.de/fileadmin/media/Dateien/3_Tickets_Preise/dokumente/TARIFPLAN_2017-Innenraum.PDF
I didn't check in detail if there is a part of Munich missing.

Comment: Wait, wait, wait this is wrong. You have free local public transport if it says "+City" **and** if you own a Bahncard. No Bahncard, no free trip. You can book the public transports with the train ticket, though (costs 2-3€ extra).

Comment: "+City" is sufficient. You usually can't buy such a ticket without checking the "I have a Bahncard" option.

Comment: You can add the _City mobil-Ticket_ (formerly _City Ticket_, which is the "+City") as a paid option if you do not select a Bahncard. In that case, it costs 5,20 EUR and only works in the destination city. If you have a Bahncard you always get a free "+City" both in the start and destination city, which is valid for the whole day, until end of service (which often is 3am of the following day). All of them have in common that they only cover an inner area of the city. In Berlin e.g. that's only zone 1 inside the ring. Every method of transport is usually included, but only 2nd class.

Comment: However, on paper tickets the "+City" option is only valid in the destination city if the ticket has been checked and validated by a conductor. I once had a very unpleasant discussion in a Berlin S-Bahn when I got into a control, because in the ICE they simply never checked the tickets, so my ticket had not been punched. If you have an online ticket, that's not an issue. For Flex-Tickets the city option in the origin city only works on the first day of validity, and in the destination on the day it's stamped, or also the first day if it's digital.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I am pretty sure that the entire city of Munich is included in the *Innenraum* as well as a few neighbouring municipalities (e.g. Planegg, Geltendorf; just two random examples I know of). When people see Munich public transport rail maps (which typically include S and U-Bahn), they typically see the entire MVV area which includes quite a bit more of the surrounding towns and villages. Most notably, the airport (near Freising) is *not* part of the Innenraum and therefore *not* accessible via City ticket.

Answer (score 10):

If the destination on your ticket is written as "München Hauptbahnhof" or "Munich Hauptbahnhof", then your ticket is only valid to that station. However, if the destination on your ticket is written as "München" or "MÜNCHEN", then a mechanism called "Tarifliche Gleichstellung" has effect, which means, that your ticket is valid to all stations within the city, which are mentioned in that document: https://www.bahn.de/p/view/mdb/bahnintern/agb/tarifliche_gleichstellung/mdb_252525_46561_20170307130917_gleichstellungen_20170201.pdf
It's only in German, but if you scroll down to "München" you see the list of train stations. Note however that this applies only to DB trains (meaning the S-Bahn in Munich, no U or trams).

Comment: How does one buy an "all stations" ticket? Whenever I enter only a city name "X" on bahn.de, it just offers tickets to "X Hbf".

Comment: I don't have the full facts, but believe this depends on the ticket. You need a long distance ticket (i.e. over 50km) not a regional ticket. International tickets might be special again, as their terms are defined on an international level ...

Comment: @Pont: Are you sure it says “X Hbf” on the actual ticket? (For an “Online-Ticket”, the actual ticket is the box with the weird background in the top left of the page.)

Comment: @chirlu I checked a couple of old PDF tickets -- sure enough, they do just say "Hamburg", not "Hamburg Hbf", even though I'm fairly sure that it was "Hbf" throughout the actual booking process! Good to know :).

Comment: Pont, your ticket is for the regional train but not for the inter city. Those are different companies. Bahn is a own company while MVG is a own aswell. You can buy a ticket for all stations on München Hauptbahnhof. There are ticketcounters aswell as machines.

Comment: @EmanuelS I’m not sure what you’re implying. If Pont’s ticket destination says *München,* Pont is entitled to continue on regional or suburban train from Munich central (or Munich East) to all stations mentioned in the PDF (which I assume to be the entirety of the suburban network within the city boundaries without having checked it). Or were you specifically referring to underground (U-Bahn) which are indeed not part of the *tarifliche Gleichstellung?*

Comment: @dunni This does *not* only apply to DB trains. OP is free to use e.g. the Meridian or the Alex if that gets them towards their destination. However, it must be a train that uses the DB rail network.

Comment: You’re right. I think it should be correct to say, that it applies to trains which accept DB fares (which includes Meridian, Alex etc. )

Answer (score 8):

As asdfex said, if it says "+City" on the ticket, you can continue to a local destination with it (but only for a single continuation of your main journey -- it's not a day travelcard).

In your case, I would expect that you don't have a city-ticket, because [the conditions](https://www.bahn.de/p/view/bahncard/vorteile/cityticket.shtml) for the city-ticket include, amongst other things, that both the start and destination stations must be in Germany.

Incidentally, I have in the past obtained free onward local travel (even for international trains) by simply making my booking to a local S-Bahn station rather than a Hauptbahnhof -- in my limited experience, the ticket price ends up the same, but I have no idea how universal this is, and of course it won't work for U-Bahn, bus, or tram.

Comment: There are some reduced fares (“Sparpreis Aktion”) that are only available if the whole journey uses ICE/IC/EC/NJ trains exclusively. You could miss out on those if you book to a minor station.

Comment: @Jan 60€ sounds like a regular Sparpreis. chirlu refers to special offers, like the 19€ tickets some month ago, or the current 25€ first class tickets.

Comment: @Jan: In addition to regular _Sparpreis_ tickets, there are also _Sparpreis Aktion_ tickets that are cheaper but come with additional restrictions (only ICE/IC category trains, no refund – not even in part). Availability is limited, but there is no maximum distance. The offer is currently valid until 2017-12-09 but may be extended. If you don’t believe me, you can have a look into DB’s [_Beförderungsbedingungen_](https://www.bahn.de/m/view/mdb/bahnintern/agb/gesamt_2017/mdb_256934_befoerderungsbedingungen-25-09-2017.pdf) (page 76).

Comment: @Jan: Or see [this entry on _Zugreiseblog_](https://www.zugreiseblog.de/bahn-sparpreis-aktion-fuer-19-euro-durch-den-winter/), which also details some of the changes the _Sparpreis Aktion_ has had during its lifetime.